# Prestashop: Combinations doesn't play well with Specific prices

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem using Prestashop which is: **Combinations doesn't play well with Specific prices.**

To reproduce:

1. Create a product and set price to 100 € (Picture 1) [image: (picture 1)]
2. Create the first combination: set Impact on price to **None** (Picture 2) [image]
3. Create the second combination: set Impact on price to **Increase** to **20€** (Picture 3) [image]
4. **So far so good.** I tested the product in front end **and it works right**
5. In Prices: create a Specific price. Set a discount of 50%. I left all other setting as default. (Picture 4)[image]

Here comes the problem which is that the price of the product stays the same regardless the combination I select. It seems to me that the **Specific prices disable the Combinations** (pictures 5 and ) [image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, I've had similar problems today, please look at my PR: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/5277

Comment: @gskema I see, please post it here if you find a fix for this. Thanks

Comment: Well in my PR I proposed a fix, which worked for me. In my case the base price is 0 and the price impact is different for each combo (it is the full price for that combo). The specific price didn't work either, because PrestaShop didn't add the price impact when calculating specific prices. You can try to make an override which I described in my PR and see if it works for you. (see the "Files changed")

Comment: @gskema Thanks for your answer. This is my first project with Prestashop, and I don't have the skills to get this done.  I thought Prestashop was a mature ecommerce with no problems of this kind. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: This bug was introduced in this version, it happens

Comment: @gskema try this https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/5087

Comment: thanks, but I am already using the fix from my PR :). Hope they fix it universally

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments it is a bug of Presta 1.6 -> https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/5277

1. When basic price is 0 and impact price is in use discounts on product combinations are not working. On product page we see good price but when added to cart - the price is 0.
2. When basic price is set > 0 and impact price is in use - discounts are not shown well.
   Simple test: Set a product price 100€. Create a combination with impact price 100€. Define a 10% discount on that combination from quantity 2. Displayed price is 90€ instead of 180€.
   And when we add that to cart price is 0 !

*issue is not present when discount added not to single combination but to all of them.

As PrestaShop 1.6 support ended on June 30, 2019 the simplest solution:

- the simplest (not the best) not use price impact with discounts on single combinations - just use basic product price then
- the best (not the simplest) go to Presta 1.7 or 8 if possible